# Objects are not valid as react child. (found object with key ...) If you meant to render a collection of children

Tags: react-native, agora.io

```
const {minutes, seconds} = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
        {minutes === 0 && seconds === 0 ? (
          this.endCall()
        ) : (
          <View
            style={{
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: '#ffffff',
                backgroundColor: THEME_COLOR,
                borderRadius: 17.5 * vw,
                padding: 6,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                fontSize: 14,
              }}>
              {minutes}:{seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}
            </Text>
          </View>
        )}

        {this._renderVideos()}
```

**End Call function:**

```
endCall = async () => {
    await _engine?.leaveChannel();
    this.setState({peerIds: [], joinSucceed: false});
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
  };
```

This code is previously working with old agora version but now i upgraded it to latest and getting this error.

When i fire endcall function from on press button then it working fine.

Comment: Why are you executing the `endCall` fn from inside the render? It doesn't render anything, why do you have it there?

Comment: what i have to do?

Comment: this code was working last time

Comment: there is a countdown of 30min after that call habe to be terminate

Comment: It may have been working, that doesn't make it the right way to do it though. Only things that pertain to render have to be inside the render. In your case you're checking 2 state values and then triggering a fn. Use `componentDidUpdate` for that.

Comment: can u share some hint

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? Have you tried running the example - https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-RN-Quickstart/?

Answer (score 0):

As [Konstantin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67125464/objects-are-not-valid-as-react-child-found-object-with-key-if-you-meant-t#comment118652516_67125464) mentioned in the comments you've got some of your react concepts mixed up, you should be calling functions that don't render anything in lifecycle methods of your app (like `componentDidMount`).

It'll help to look at the Agora React Native [example app](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-RN-Quickstart/) and follow the code from there.